# Collection of maps on a split abelian complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Suppose we have a complex of abelian groups with direct sum $C_{\ast}=H_{\ast}\oplus B_{\ast} \oplus D_{\ast}$.

Let $s_{\ast}=\{s_{n}\}$ be the collection of maps such that $s_{n} : C_{n} \rightarrow C_{n+1}$ where $d_{n}s_{n-1}d_{n}=d_{n}$ for any $n$.

Define $f_{n}: C_{n} \rightarrow C_{n}$  where $f_{n}=s_{n-1}d_{n}$ and; $f'_{n}: C_{n} \rightarrow C_{n}$ where $f'_{n}=d_{n+1}s_{n}$.

I know that for any $n >0$ then $d_{n}d_{n+1}=0$. How do I see the following :

- $f_{n}f'_{n}= s_{n-1}d_{n}d_{n+1}s_{n}=0$
- $d_{n}f'_{n}=d_{n}d_{n+1}s_{n}=0$

Furthermore;
If I let $g_{n}=(1-f’_{n})f_{n}$ I seem to struggle with understanding why $g_{n}^{2}=g_{n}$.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: 'homological-algebra' might be a more appropriate tag.

Comment: @feynhat I’m not sure that’s an existing tag, should I create a new tag?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't see how the composition $s_nd_{n-1}$ makes sense. Edit: BTW, it is an existing tag.

Comment: @feynhat Oh sorry that was a typo, I have now corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two results are trivial because $d_nd_{n+1} = 0$.

Next, $f_nf_n = s_{n-1}d_ns_{n-1}d_n = s_{n-1}d_n = f_n$

$g_n = (\text{id} - f'_n)f_n = f_n - f'_nf_n$

$g_n^2 = (f_n - f'_nf_n)(f_n - f'_nf_n) = f_nf_n - f_nf'_nf_n - f'_nf_nf_n + f'_nf_nf'_nf_n$.

The second and last terms are $0$, because $f_nf_n' = 0$.

$g_n^2 = f_nf_n - f'_nf_nf_n = (\text{id} -f_n')f_nf_n = (\text{id} -f_n')f_n = g_n$.